# D3 overlay heatmap onto a map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

I am trying to create a grid heatmap from csv values(with rows, columns, and count) and then overlay the heatmap onto a map(google-maps,or any static map image would also do). The grid is a 2d grid of latitudes and longitudes.Any help would be appreciated.

I have looked at this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3202354 , and have an idea of how to draw the heatmap.

I am trying to create something like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606 , but dont have the GeoJSON values.

Comment: In general, you will get much better responses on StackOverflow if you have a specific question you can formulate, with some code you've already written. Where are you stuck? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

`http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606` is not a google map overlay. d3.map(); suggests perhaps a dom with an array of state objects. so your goal is simply to sequence your data in the proper order. just a guess.

further, i bet  tsv is tab separated value (opposed to your comma separated value). no big deal at all.

```
var rateById = d3.map(); // looks like assigning this map dom to a var
...

.defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); }) // this one appears to be assigning the tsv data to the dom map, the above var
```